# AbstractCollection class of Module Reports is not overriding

Tags: magento2, reports

I am trying to override this class

```
Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\AbstractCollection
```

This is a simple class not abstract class

Here is some code example of core class

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection;

/**
 * Report collection abstract model
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class AbstractCollection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * From date
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_from = null;

    /**
     * To date
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_to = null;
```

But when i am trying to override this class in my custom module than it is not overriding.

Here is the code which i am writing for override

**app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\AbstractCollection" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Rewrite\Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\AbstractCollection"/>
</config>
```

**app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Rewrite/Magento/Reports/Model/ResourceModel/Report/Collection/AbstractCollection.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Rewrite\Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection;

class AbstractCollection extends \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _applyStoresFilterToSelect(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select $select)
    {
        echo "i want to override this method"; die;
    }
}
```

After writing this code. Methods of that class are still showing content from the core class.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot override the Abstract Class

Comment: Check your custom and third party modules, same class is override or not in any modules. Di file is in etc, and no, it's not override by thrd party modules.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error, fetch override another file so, You need to remove generated, var/* after the cache clean and check again.

**Change** _applyStoresFilterToSelec **to** _applyStoresFilter

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Rewrite/Magento/Reports/Model/ResourceModel/Report/Collection/AbstractCollection.php

---

```
 <?php
 declare(strict_types=1);

 namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Rewrite\Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection;
 
 class AbstractCollection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
 {

     protected function _applyStoresFilter()
     {
         return $this->_applyStoresFilterToSelect($this->getSelect());
     }
  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\AbstractCollection` class does not instantiate by Object Manager, so you can not use `preference` to override this class.

`Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\AbstractGrid` class has `getCountTotals()` method that create `Collection` based on resource collection name which extends `Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\AbstractCollection`. Eg:

- Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Order\Collection
- Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection
- Magento\Tax\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection
- ...

So, to achieve your goal: override `Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\AbstractCollection::_applyStoresFilter`, you should determine which Grids you would like to implement, then override the corresponding Collection class that declare in `getResourceCollectionName` method of Grid class.

Eg, if you want to override `Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\AbstractCollection::_applyStoresFilter` in Bestsellers grid, you have to override `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection`:

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Rewrite\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection"/>
```

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Rewrite/Magento/Sales/Model/ResourceModel/Report/Bestsellers/Collection.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Rewrite\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers;
 
class Collection extends \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection
 {
     protected function _applyStoresFilterToSelect(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select $select)
     {
         echo 'you are now able to override the parent method'; die;
     }
 }
```